# Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter' in target sdk 23

Tags: android, spinner, android-support-library

I am getting Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter' while creating Array adapter for spinner. Other stackoverflow result were of no help. How to solve this?
What are the alternatives to use the spinner?

Code:

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/country_code" 
         android:layout_width="0dp" 
         android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_5_dp"
         android:layout_weight="2" 
         android:entries="@array/country_codes" 
         android:background="@drawable/spinner_background" 
         android:prompt="@string/country_code_hint" />
```

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/country_code"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_5_dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:entries="@array/country_codes"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                    android:prompt="@string/country_code_hint" />

Answer (score 0):

Try to change all of Compile versions to the SDK 22.

Comment: I mean all of them in build.gradle.

Comment: Downgraded support libraries to 22. Now i am getiing at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource null pointer exception, i am using system layouts